# Double For-loop scanning 2 entire columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I've got a huge dataset about couples that looks something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Partner1_ID =   c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999), 
                   Partner2_ID =   c(222, 111, 001, 777, 002, 003, 444, 004, 005), 
                   biol_sex_1 =  c("male", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
                                   "male", "male", "male"), 
                   biol_sex_2 = NA)
data

    Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
1         111         222       male         NA
2         222         111     female         NA
3         333           1     female         NA
4         444         777       male         NA
5         555           2       male         NA
6         666           3     female         NA
7         777         444       male         NA
8         888           4       male         NA
9         999           5       male         NA
```

Every row consists of the ID number of Partner1, the ID number of Partner2, the biological sex of Partner1, and the biological sex of Partner2, which is `NA` for now

I want to fill in the values for `biol_sex_2` now. The information of Partner2's biological sex is already somewhere in the column `biol_sex_1`. For example, we can see that in rows 1 and 2 I have a couple since their ID's match. The same is true for rows 4 and 7, my second couple.

As soon as I find a couple (by matching ID's), I want to take the `biol_sex_1` of the **first** Partner and assign it's value to the `biol_sex_2` of the **second** Partner and vice versa.

I tried this nasty double for loop (I still don't get a simple for loop 100% to be honest)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
  
  if (data$Partner1_ID[i] == data$Partner2_ID[j]) {
    data$biol_sex_2[i] <- data$biol_sex_1[j]
  }
  
  else {
    (data$biol_sex_2[i] <- 0)
  }
  }
}
```

but my computer has been running since an hour on it (again, very large dataset...), so I thought I give it a try here.

I don't insist on a double for loop. I am sure there are other more elegant (and faster, I guess...) ways. But if someone could come up with a double for loop, I would highly appreciate that as well as I would really like to see how to do it.

Thanks a lot <3

Comment: I think the only issue with your double for loop is the `(data$biol_sex_2[i] <- 0)` line. Every time there's not a match, you set `biol_sex_2` to 0. When you find a match, you set `biol_sex_2` to the correct value, and then the next iteration doesn't match so it resets it to 0. If you delete the entire `else` condition so that no action is taken when there isn't a match, I think it will work.

Comment: You could also speed things up **a lot** if you created a way to force `i` to iterate as soon as you find a match in `j`. As written, if you find a match when `j = 1` your loop still iterates over all the rest of the rows looking for another match. Making the inner loop a `while` loop could work, or replacing the inner loop with `match()`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I've been trying out your first suggestion for 10mins now (computer still running), so not sure if this will give something... concerning your second suggestion, I'm not sure to have understood it completely. I will have a look at the ```while``` and ```match()``` things. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd strongly suggest trying out solutions on small data. Give yourself a 10 row subset of data to test whether things work - just like in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed double-for and while loop versions on your sample data:

```
## just deleted your `else{}`
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (data$Partner1_ID[i] == data$Partner2_ID[j]) {
      data$biol_sex_2[i] <- data$biol_sex_1[j]
    }
  }
}

# looks right
data
#   Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
# 1         111         222       male     female
# 2         222         111     female       male
# 3         333           1     female       <NA>
# 4         444         777       male       male
# 5         555           2       male       <NA>
# 6         666           3     female       <NA>
# 7         777         444       male       male
# 8         888           4       male       <NA>
# 9         999           5       male       <NA>

## reset the test data
data$biol_sex_2 = NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  j <- 1
  while(is.na(data$biol_sex_2[i]) && j <= nrow(data)) {
    if (data$Partner1_ID[i] == data$Partner2_ID[j]) {
      data$biol_sex_2[i] <- data$biol_sex_1[j]
    }
    j <- j + 1
  }
}
data # also looks right
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  dplyr::select(-biol_sex_2) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(data %>% 
                      dplyr::select(Partner1_ID, biol_sex_2 = biol_sex_1),
                    by = c("Partner2_ID" = "Partner1_ID"))

  Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
1         111         222       male     female
2         222         111     female       male
3         333           1     female       <NA>
4         444         777       male       male
5         555           2       male       <NA>
6         666           3     female       <NA>
7         777         444       male       male
8         888           4       male       <NA>
9         999           5       male       <NA>
```

Alternatively if you want to insist on a for loop:

```
for (i in data$Partner2_ID) {
  data$biol_sex_2[data$Partner2_ID == i] <- if (length(data$biol_sex_1[data$Partner1_ID == i]) != 1) {
    NA_character_
  } else {
    data$biol_sex_1[data$Partner1_ID == i]
  }
}

  Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
1         111         222       male     female
2         222         111     female       male
3         333           1     female       <NA>
4         444         777       male       male
5         555           2       male       <NA>
6         666           3     female       <NA>
7         777         444       male       male
8         888           4       male       <NA>
9         999           5       male       <NA>
```

Comment: it did! thank you very much! Of course this would have been much easier using joins, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Still, any idea how this could be done with a double for-loop as well?

Comment: I don't think a double for loop is needed - just a single one with an if statement - see my alternate answer

Answer (score 1):

**base**

```r
df <- data.frame(Partner1_ID =   c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999), 
                   Partner2_ID =   c(222, 111, 001, 777, 002, 003, 444, 004, 005), 
                   biol_sex_1 =  c("male", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", 
                                   "male", "male", "male"), 
                   biol_sex_2 = NA)


df$biol_sex_2 <- df$biol_sex_1[with(df, match(Partner2_ID, table = Partner1_ID))]
df
#>   Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
#> 1         111         222       male     female
#> 2         222         111     female       male
#> 3         333           1     female       <NA>
#> 4         444         777       male       male
#> 5         555           2       male       <NA>
#> 6         666           3     female       <NA>
#> 7         777         444       male       male
#> 8         888           4       male       <NA>
#> 9         999           5       male       <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
# set column biol_sex_2 as character for joining, 
#  since it is not defined in sample data
data[, biol_sex_2 := as.character(biol_sex_2)]
data[ data, biol_sex_2 := i.biol_sex_1, on = .(Partner1_ID = Partner2_ID)]

#    Partner1_ID Partner2_ID biol_sex_1 biol_sex_2
# 1:         111         222       male     female
# 2:         222         111     female       male
# 3:         333           1     female       <NA>
# 4:         444         777       male       male
# 5:         555           2       male       <NA>
# 6:         666           3     female       <NA>
# 7:         777         444       male       male
# 8:         888           4       male       <NA>
# 9:         999           5       male       <NA>
```